# LTSpice: Unknown circuit node using LMC662

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, error

I am trying to simulate a simple circuit using the opamp LMC662 from Texas Instruments. I imported the file as provided in the product website: www.ti.com/product/LMC662/toolssoftware 
However whenever I run any simulation i get the error: 
**G4: unknown circuit node: "1" requested in behavioral source.** 
I have no idea what this means and how to solve it. Only thing that I found is that in the model file there are the lines:

G4  98 16 POLY(2) **1** 49 2 49 0 3.54E-8 3.54E-8

G4  98 16 POLY(2) **1** 49 2 49 0 3.54E-8 3.54E-8

which refer to node 1, which is defined as the non-inverting input of the opamp:

.SUBCKT LMC662/NS   1   2  99  50  28

Im attaching a screenshot of the schematic.[image: simulation stops with this error]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: The ltspice model is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmQXDTgCDE36sQRCyOF_s3o26Z5r) (it's in the zip file).

Comment: can you share the LTSpice file too?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to include it.

Comment: couldn't download. able to see file in onedrive. can you check?

Comment: hmm that is strange. I am able to download the zip file without being logged in to Onedrive. Can you check again? Initially I had uploaded just the .asc file but afterwards I uploaded a zip containing the whole project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by using a different library from National Instruments which contained the LMC662/NS. It can be found [here](http://home.broadpark.no/~pbrakken/el2/avgrensa/SPICE-modeller/nat_semi.lib). I still have no idea what was wrong with the original one.